# Add logo to RSS feed code

Tags: rss, feed, vbulletin

I'm wondering how to add a logo or image to my rss feed. I want to do that at my vbulletin forum. it has rss feed property and contain the following codes:

**Title Template:**

```
{feed:title}
```

**Body Template:**

```
{feed:description}

[url={feed:link}]more details...[/url]
```

now, I was reading somewhere around about this and came up with some ideas "not sure they would work though". I have to wrap the body template with a **`div`** then add **`<img>`** inside it the place where I want, but still no success...

possibly I'm missing something... also I wonder if I can add the image to the Title template instead of the body template!!!

Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but :
(for vB4)

You can use several rss field AND BBCODE, so you can use an image like :

**Body Template:**

> [img]http://myimg.com/logo1.gif[/img]
>
> [B]{feed:title}[/B] posted {feed:date} by [B]{feed:author}[/B] :
>
> {feed:content}

I think you can not use BBCODE on the title template.

Comment: excellent, mate. Thanks a lot. didn't know that I could use BBcodes in my rss fileds!